# UITableView crashes because "Attempt to create two animations for cell" (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

In an UITableView I am trying to exchange the position of two sections and to add a new row into one of them by using a batch update.

BEFORE:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|                                     |
|                                     |
| SECTION A - HEADER - TITLE          |
|-------------------------------------|
| SECTION A - ROW X                   |
|-------------------------------------|
| SECTION A - ROW Y                 > |
|-------------------------------------|
|                                     |
|                                     |
|-------------------------------------|
| SECTION B - ROW X                   |
|-------------------------------------|
|                                     |
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

AFTER:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|                                     |
|                                     |
|-------------------------------------|
| SECTION B - ROW X                   |
|-------------------------------------|
|                                     |
|                                     |
| SECTION A - HEADER - TITLE          |
|-------------------------------------|
| SECTION A - ROW X                   |
|-------------------------------------|
| SECTION A - ROW Z - NEW ROW         | <---------
|-------------------------------------|
| SECTION A - ROW Y                 > |
|-------------------------------------|
|                                     |
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Here is my code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView moveSection:from toSection:to]; // from: 0, to: 1
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; // indexPath.section: 1, indexPath.row: 1
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

But the UITableView instance crashes and outputs the following:

```
2014-06-29 19:45:07.486 YouTube[3312:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableViewSupport.m:1173
2014-06-29 19:45:07.488 YouTube[3312:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102447495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001021a699e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010244731a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000101d42f19 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010101166c -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] + 7491
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010101aa81 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 193
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100e10615 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 1639
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100e0c000 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 11615
    ...
```

Is it not possible to move a section and add a new row at the same time in a batch update?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but just ran into this myself on iOS 11.3. We have code that diffs old and new models and generates UITableView updates, and it explodes with the "more than one animation for cell" exception when a section is both moved **and** has any changes to its cells (insert/delete/update).

The only solution is to delete/insert the section in this case, rather than move. You could either always do this (and probably animate sub-optimally), or do what we do and track when cells change and do the move only when safe.

Comment: This scenario was causing a crash with `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`'s under the same circumstances. I was sorting sections by date, and fixed it by including the date in the hash for each section identifier (so the section is considered a new section altogether, and gets deleted then inserted).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I ran into the issue too (I used diffable data source with UITableView) and had no idea what went wrong until found your explanation. Not sure if the issue's specific to UITableView (because it's not actively developed by Apple) or it occurs with newer technology too (e.g., UICollectionview, SwiftUI).

Answer (score 0):

You should change dataSources as well.

```
- (void)exchangeTableSection
{
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        NSMutableArray *temp = self.data1;
        self.data1 = self.data2;
        self.data2 = temp;
        [self.data1 insertObject:@"ROW Z - NEW ROW " atIndex:1];

        [self.tableView moveSection:0 toSection:1];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
        return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        if (0 == section) {
                return self.data1.count;
        } else if (1 == section) {
                return self.data2.count;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sundea: Data source is already updated correctly. I mean, I saw that it is possible to just move the section or to insert the row. But it seems not to be possible to have both in one batch update. It is also possible to create two separate batch updates for each moving and inserting, but this solution makes data source handling a bit complicated. So, I just want to set the data source once and commit all required move, delete, insert requests in one batch update block.

Comment: @selcuksinan My code works well, it moves sections and inserts rows in one update.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. Please have a look at the example project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/53841l6ocgblhvy/Example.zip You can try each three options in method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (in ViewController.m). You will see, that only the first two work, but not the last one.

Comment: @selcuksinan In your example, change moving section code to `[self.tableView moveSection:1 toSection:0];` it will work

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. It really works. But what is the difference? I mean, I also tried now to insert new rows in both sections while moving them and it works fine, too. But what is wrong with  moving section 0 to 1 instead of 1 to 0? I have to understand the rule here, because I have a TableViewManager, which automatically creates these method calls (moving/deleting/inserting sections and row) and it has to consider those rules.

Comment: @selcuksinan I'm wrestling with the exact same problem. It seems that the moveSection is completely and utterly broken for use-case such as ours. Take a table with 2 sections, both containing 2 rows. Mark both first rows as deleted and inserted (replaced basically) and then try to move section 0 -> 1 or 1 -> 0. For both cases the exception is thrown. :(